# All android support libraries must use the same version specification

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I dont know where I went wrong, but this keeps me saying

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the same exact version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes.) Found versions 24.0.0,23.2.0 Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0
```

my build.gradle is

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.2.2'
    compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It shows error in this line too

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

I tried changing compileSdkVersion to 24 too, but nothing seems to work as of now. Actually everything was working fine before I introduced the play services library.

Comment: what is your compile Sdk version? post the full gradle

Comment: Hi @rafsanahmad007 , I have edited the post. Thanks

Comment: One or more of your dependencies are requesting portions of the Android Support Library and are requesting different versions of that library. You will need to track down which dependency that is (e.g., via the Gradle dependency report), then address the problem (e.g., via adding your own `compile` line for that transitive dependency that requests the newer version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dependency is using version 24.0.0 of com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

which will cause android studio to complain that it could lead to bugs/crashes because versions of all your google libraries don't match.

**So you have 2 options:** *(that I know of off the top of my head)*

1. Change your `compileSdkVersion` to 24 and change all your support library dependencies to version 24 as well to match the play-services dependencies:

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
   ```
2. Downgrade `com.google.android.gms:play-services` to 9.4 or 9.2.1 so that it doesn't use version 24 of anything. This still requires a minor change to your support libraries from 23.2.0 to simply 23.0.0

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
   ```