# OneSignal and Gradle error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, onesignal

I dont know where I went wrong, but this keeps me saying

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the same exact version
specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes.) Found
versions 25.3.1, 24.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated
vector-drawable:25.3.1 and com.android.support:customtabs-v7:24.0.0
```

my build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cosmic.com.fest"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

flavorDimensions "server"

productFlavors {

    local {
        applicationId "cosmic.com.fest.local"
        dimension 'server'
    }

    dev {
        applicationId "cosmic.com.fest"
        dimension 'server'
    }
  }



defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "something",
    onesignal_google_project_number: "something"]
  }
}

def ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION = "25.3.1"

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.1'
compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.15'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
compile "com.android.support:design:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION"
compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION"
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION"

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'

compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.5.6'

// Required for OneSignal, even if you have added FCM.
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'

// Required for geotagging
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.6"

// play-services-analytics is only needed when using 8.1.0 or older.
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.6'
}
```

I need to add OneSignal notifications with Firebase to obtain tokens.

When I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43307797/3913366) solution, my `appcompat` would still complain the same.

Comment: run `gradlew dependencies` on the command line to see where the version 24.0.0 is pulled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

Actually I was changing the `ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION` to `24.0.0` which changed all library version. Once I did,

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
```

problem solved.